# ifconfig made my server unreachable

Tags: linux, debian, networking, ip, ifconfig

I just got a second IP address for my Debian Squeeze root. I tried to add the address to my network but somehow I messed up. The command I executed: 
`ifconfig eth0 [new ip address] mask 255.255.255.254`

Now, I cant get any response from the server e.g. Apache, ftp etc.

I did not try to restart it yet.
Is there any possibility to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't add the second IP address, but instead replaced the first IP address.

You should be able to access the server via that second IP address, if the netmask is correct and any firewall allows access to that IP address.

For reference, it's easiest IMHO to add extra IP addresses via:

```
ip addr add newip/32 dev eth0
```

Use `/32` if the new address is within the same netmask as an existing IP address, otherwise use the real netmask (in your case /31 for 255.255.255.254).

Removal is done with e.g.:

```
ip addr del newip/32 dev eth0
```

If the extra Ip address is permanent, add a line to the `iface eth0 inet static` paragraph:

```
up ip addr add newip/32 dev eth0
```

Comment: I already tried to connect via the second IP address but it fails. Is there any other possibility? Is my hoster able to change anything? Will a restart do anything?

Comment: A restart should restore the system to normal operation, as long as you haven't been editing the config to add that ifconfig command line somewhere.